# Does SWRL support classical negation in Protege?

Tags: owl, protege, negation, swrl

I wanted to try the following rule:

`(not Person)(?x) -> NonHuman(?x)` which is provided  here - https://github.com/protegeproject/swrlapi/wiki/SWRLLanguageFAQ#does-swrl-support-classical-negation

and i got this:
[image]

Is classical negation supported in Protege 5.5.0? If yes, how I can make the following rule to be okay?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, it's not supported: https://github.com/protegeproject/swrlapi/issues/63

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://github.com/protegeproject/swrlapi/issues/63:

> Unfortunately, the SWRLAPI's parser does not support OWL class expressions in rules.
>   There is no timeline for their inclusion.

Fortunately, one can use the Rules view (*Windows > Views > Ontology Views > Rules*):

`Rule: (not Person)(?x) -> NonHuman(?x)` is parsed correctly and works as intended.

---

Actually, you do not need SWRL in this particlular case. Just write `(not Person) SubClassOf NonHuman` in the *General class axioms* section, or define `NonPerson` first, if you don't like GCI axioms.

Don't forget about the OWA.

Comment: The thing is I wanted to test negation with SWRL rule, since it says the classical one is supported in the docs. As far as I got the built-in `swrlb:notEqual()` seems to work, but non-built-in would be more appreciated :).

Comment: @mastaofthepasta, then you can write `Rule: (not Person)(?x) -> NonHuman(?x)` in the Rules view. To be honest, I can't undestand your answer. `swrlb:notEqual` requires two (literal) arguments.

Comment: That's weird... my answer solution says that the status is `OK` when I am creating a rule in the SQWRLTab, while `(not Person)(?x) -> NonHuman(?x)` says its not okay as it is mentioned on the picture in the question.

Comment: @mastaofthepasta, the Rules view: *Rules view: Windows > Views > Ontology Views > Rules*. Your rule does nothing, btw.