# swrl rule specify individual that is not part of class

Tags: protege, swrl

I can't find a solution to this swrl rule.
let's say I have a class named 'AmericanCity', and a class named 'CanadianCity', and I have a 3rd class named 'NotAmerican'.. how can I say that if an individual x doesn't belong to the AmericanCity class, then it is NotAmerican?

Comment: that would only work if it would explicitly defined for the individual to not be instance of a class. Note, in OWL and therefore in SWRL the Open World Assumption holds. Absence of information doesn't mean the negation holds

Comment: HTH: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59810271